# Is there a way to copy text from html package

Tags: flutter, flutter-html

I use the [fluter_html package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html). Is there a way, to make the text Copyable? The Html Widget is in a CustomScrollView with a SliverList. I want to copy the text without the html stuff. As an example, I want to copy "Hello, copy me" and not "Hello `<br>` copy me"

Edit: I want to copy on Android and MacOs Desktop
This is my Html Widget.

```
                  Html(
                      data: singleNews.text,
                      style: {
                        "body": Style(
                          fontSize: FontSize(
                              (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) / 70),
                        )
                      },
                      onLinkTap: (url, _, __, ___) async {
                        if (await canLaunch(url!)) {
                          await launch(url);
                          _log.i("Opening $url...");
                        } else {
                          _log.e('Could not launch $url');
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: Where do you copy content?

Comment: @Muhtar i want to copy on MacOs Desktop and on Android

Comment: I meant in code context

Comment: @Muhtar I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. I get data from an api. In singleNews.text is only the html text. I want to copy it from my app. Like in Word. If I tap long, I want a Button that say copy. Then it should copy the text on the screen and not the html data

Comment: you may want to use webview plugin for it but I am not sure if it fits this context.

Comment: @Muhtar It doesn't work with that. Thats not what I want. For Example, the text is "Helolpifhs <br> wipufwhflwfhowöfwö <br>" And it should show only the text without <br>. That's why I need the Html package. Now I want to copy the text like in web. If it's on MacOs

Comment: You can show local html with  webview and you can copy content without html content. As I saw it works fine on android, but not sure on MacOs

Comment: That doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the docs it looks like the package has a 'Selectable' option, so just change your widget from `Html` to `SelectableHtml`, which will give you the desired function, you will be able to select the text and a tooltip will appear with the 'Copy' option.

https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_html/latest/flutter_html/SelectableHtml-class.html

Comment: I am facing an issue while using the SelectableHtml widget. Like some of the HTML is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Since Flutter 3, you can use `SelectionArea` to control select behavior.

It is worth mentioning that `flutter_html` no longer includes `SelectableHtml` since v3.x.